# I get the following error when i try to execute my code. SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma

Tags: sql, oracle

My query in Oracle keeps saying i have a missing comma error. I don't see any missing comma. Please help

```
INSERT INTO TBLTEACHER (TEACHERID,FIRSTNAME,SURNAME,LOGINUMBER,COURSEID) VALUES 
(100,"Jessica, Janet, Robert, Jonathon","Davies, Smith, Clarkson, Campbell",2i,1),
(101,"Jessica, Janet, Robert, Jonathon","Davies, Smith, Clarkson, Campbell",6i,2),
(102,"Jessica, Janet, Robert, Jonathon","Davies, Smith, Clarkson, Campbell",10i,3),
(103,"Jessica, Janet, Robert, Jonathon","Davies, Smith, Clarkson, Campbell",14i,4),
```

Comment: It's the double quotes. You need single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not allow the insertion of multiple rows using values.  So use multiple inserts.

In addition, Oracle does not support double quotes for strings.  And something like `2i` doesn't make sense unless it is a string.  So, the following would seem to insert the rows you want:

```
INSERT INTO TBLTEACHER (TEACHERID,FIRSTNAME,SURNAME,LOGINUMBER,COURSEID) 
    VALUES (100, 'Jessica, Janet, Robert, Jonathon', 'Davies, Smith, Clarkson, Campbell', '2i', 1);
INSERT INTO TBLTEACHER (TEACHERID,FIRSTNAME,SURNAME,LOGINUMBER,COURSEID) 
    VALUES (101, 'Jessica, Janet, Robert, Jonathon', 'Davies, Smith, Clarkson, Campbell', '6i',2);
INSERT INTO TBLTEACHER (TEACHERID,FIRSTNAME,SURNAME,LOGINUMBER,COURSEID) 
    VALUES (102, 'Jessica, Janet, Robert, Jonathon', 'Davies, Smith, Clarkson, Campbell', '10i', 3);
INSERT INTO TBLTEACHER (TEACHERID,FIRSTNAME,SURNAME,LOGINUMBER,COURSEID) 
    VALUES (103, 'Jessica, Janet, Robert, Jonathon', 'Davies, Smith, Clarkson, Campbell', '14i', 4);
```

I find it strange that you are putting lists in a string and inserting them, but that is another matter.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. i tried it however the same error comes up,                              
                                                                                                                               Error starting at line : 7 in command -
INSERT INTO TBLTEACHER (TEACHERID,FIRSTNAME,SURNAME,LOGINUMBER,COURSEID) 
    VALUES (103,"Jessica, Janet, Robert, Jonathon","Davies, Smith, Clarkson, Campbell",14i,4)
Error at Command Line : 8 Column : 90
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma
00917. 00000 -  "missing comma"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @S.K - The code you posted is still using double quotes not single quotes as Gordon's example is showing.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to select statement with union all clauses, and replace double-quotes with single-quotes, and take other non-quoted alpha-numeric values into single-quotes :

```
INSERT INTO TBLTEACHER (TEACHERID,FIRSTNAME,SURNAME,LOGINUMBER,COURSEID)
SELECT 100,'Jessica, Janet, Robert, Jonathon','Davies, Smith, Clarkson, Campbell','2i' ,1  FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 101,'Jessica, Janet, Robert, Jonathon','Davies, Smith, Clarkson, Campbell','6i' ,2  FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 102,'Jessica, Janet, Robert, Jonathon','Davies, Smith, Clarkson, Campbell','10i',3  FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 103,'Jessica, Janet, Robert, Jonathon','Davies, Smith, Clarkson, Campbell','14i',4  FROM dual;
```

Alternatively use `INSERT ALL` clause :

```
INSERT ALL 
  INTO TBLTEACHER VALUES(100,'Jessica, Janet, Robert, Jonathon','Davies, Smith, Clarkson, Campbell','2i' ,1)
  INTO TBLTEACHER VALUES(101,'Jessica, Janet, Robert, Jonathon','Davies, Smith, Clarkson, Campbell','6i' ,2)
  INTO TBLTEACHER VALUES(102,'Jessica, Janet, Robert, Jonathon','Davies, Smith, Clarkson, Campbell','10i',3)
  INTO TBLTEACHER VALUES(103,'Jessica, Janet, Robert, Jonathon','Davies, Smith, Clarkson, Campbell','14i',4)
SELECT 1 FROM dual;
```

P.S. If number of comma-seperated components within the `VALUES` clause equals number of the columns of the table, then there's no need to write them explicitly.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b093c5cd5a7fe07f414d87aba88c4998)</kbd>